# Building app with blocks in Sencha Touch 2?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

my question is related to building GUIs on Sencha Touch 2 creating first the controls and then instantiating them on a panel's items. Like so:

```
var myButton = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
    text: 'Button',
});
```

And then do this in order to show it on screen:

```
//..some panel
items:[{myButton}, {anotherControl}]
```

When I try to do this on Sencha Touch 2, it just throws an error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

I used to do this on Sencha Touch 1.x and this is driving me crazy because in every example I find in the net, they declare the controls inside the panel using the xtype property.

A small code snippet would be great help for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like so :

```
Ext.define('App.view.MyView', {
  xtype: 'myview',

  extend: 'Ext.Panel',

  config: {
    layout: 'vbox'
  },

  constructor: function() {
    var me = this;
    me.callParent(arguments);

    var myButton1 = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
        text: 'Button1',
    });

    var myButton2 = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
        text: 'Button2',
    });

   me.add([myButton1,myButton2]);
  }
});
```

Hope this helps